# What is an efficient way to bulk insert pyarrow Table into MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, pyarrow

A related library `pymongoarrow` supports retrieving mongo query results in the `pyarrow.Table` format, but there is no similar method for (bulk) inserting `pyarrow.Table`s into mongo.

One way is insert to convert the `pyarrow.Table` to a list of dictionaries using `to_pylist()` method, but then it will not be able to load more data than the memory (in case of huge data).

Answer (score 0):

If the table, when converted with `to_pylist()`, doesn't fit into memory, you can try to work on [`RecordBatch`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.RecordBatch.html) instead, using [`to_reader`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.Table.html#pyarrow.Table.to_reader)

```py
for batch in table.to_reader(max_chunk_size=10000):
  batch.to_pylist()
```